# Group with multiple fields, but treat the fields as equal

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Assuming that I have data for travel information between two cities. For exmaple,

```
{ from: 'Paris', to: 'New York' }
{ from: 'New York', to: 'Paris' },
{ from: 'London', to: 'Moscow' },
{ from: 'Paris', to: 'New York' }
// etc...
```

I'd like to count the number of times a trip between certain cities has been made. The trick is that a trip from London to Moscow should be treated the same as a trip from Moscow to London, i.e. the direction of the trip does no matter. **How can I achieve this with mongodb aggregation framework?**

A simple grouping by the two fields will not ignore the direction

```
db.trips.aggregate([
  {$group: { _id: { from: "$from", to: "$to" }, count: { $sum: 1} } }
])
```

and will lead to the following results

```
{ _id: {from: 'New York', to: 'Paris'}, count: 1 },
{ _id: {from: 'London', to: 'Moscom'}, count: 1 },
{ _id: {from: 'Paris', to: 'New York'}, count: 2 }
// etc...
```

but I'd want it to state that a trip between Paris and New York has been made 3 times.

P.S. The title of this post probably does not describe quite well what I want to achieve, but unfortunately I cannot think of a better one at the time. So, feel free to modify as seen fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very interesting question. I found a way, a little bit tricky, but it's doing the job.

**Quick answer:**

```
db.travels.aggregate([
    {
        $project:
        {
            city1:
            {
                $cond: { if: { $gte: [ "$from", "$to" ] }, then: "$to", else: "$from" }
            },
            city2:
            {
                $cond: { if: { $lt: [ "$from", "$to" ] }, then: "$to", else: "$from" }
            }
        }
    }
    ,{
        $group: 
        { 
            _id: 
            { 
                from: "$city1",
                to: "$city2"
            }
            ,count: { $sum: 1}
        }
    }
])
```

**Explaination:**

First, using $project I use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to order the `$from` and the `$to` alphabetically. The `city1` (new $from) is always the city with the "smallest" letter in alphabetical order. and `city2` is always the "biggest".

Then, at the end of the `$project`, I have what you need, and I use your `$group` (btw, you have a typo in your code, the `count` should be before the bracket).

**Result:**

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "from": "London",
        "to": "Moscow"
      },
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "from": "New York",
        "to": "Paris"
      },
      "count": 3
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code in example was something I wrote just for SO, but fixed the bracketing nevertheless. I'll examine this solution more closely and get back on this.

Comment: Confirmed that this solution is valid.